# MVC3 export to excel - lambda expression change the encode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, export-to-excel

I'm using entity framework.
I export a table to excel in this way:

```
DetailsSet TheDetails = db.DetailsSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + ".xls";
            StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            // var List = db.GetRegList(TheDetails.CorrectAnswer);
            List<RegistrationSet> RegList = TheDetails.RegistrationSet.Where(x => x.Answer == TheDetails.CorrectAnswer).ToList();
            dgGrid.DataSource = RegList;
            dgGrid.DataBind();
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");

            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
```

The issue is that in the excel, all the text in hebrew from the db is shown like gibresh.
 When I remove the `.Where(x => x.Answer == TheDetails.CorrectAnswer)` from the grid, the excel is OK - means all the texts in hebrew is OK.

**Like This is OK:**

```
List<RegistrationSet> RegList = TheDetails.RegistrationSet.ToList();
```

but like this, is not OK:

```
List<RegistrationSet> RegList = TheDetails.RegistrationSet.Where(x => x.Answer == TheDetails.CorrectAnswer).ToList();
```

Full example of OK Function:

```
DetailsSet TheDetails = db.DetailsSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + ".xls";
            StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            // var List = db.GetRegList(TheDetails.CorrectAnswer);
            List<RegistrationSet> RegList = TheDetails.RegistrationSet.ToList();
            dgGrid.DataSource = RegList;
            dgGrid.DataBind();
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");

            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
```

Fixed the problem